# Fails freeing Interface implemented class

Tags: delphi, class, interface, free

I opened a similar topic before, but I had no clear reason for error **"invalid pointer operation"** when trying to free the class instance. Now I already know the reason so I open a new topic, to expose the problem.

So the reason for this error is when instantiating the class ChatClient and pass as a parameter the instance of the class itself (TChatManager). Probably the problem is related to the implementation of the class TChatManager to the interface.

**Interface:**

```
Type
  // An interface definition
  IMessageEvents = Interface(IInterface)
    ['{BD27EFC6-CC9A-437A-A8B8-16F722518836}']

    Procedure messageReceived(messageData: String);
  End;
```

**Class TChatManager:**

```
Type
  TChatManager = Class(TInterfacedObject, IMessageEvents)
  Private
    cChatClient: TChatClient;
  Protected
    Procedure messageReceived(messageData: String); Overload;
  Public
    Constructor Create; Overload;
    Destructor Destroy; Override;
  End;

Implementation

Constructor TChatManager.Create;
Begin
  Inherited Create;
  self.cChatClient := TChatClient.Create(self); // self class instance as parameter
End;

Procedure TChatManager.messageReceived(messageData: String);
Begin

End;

Destructor TChatManager.Destroy;
Begin
  Inherited Destroy;
End;
```

**Class TChatClient:**

```
Type
  TChatClient = Class(TObject)
  Private
    iMsgEvents: IMessageEvents;
  Protected
  Public
    Constructor Create(iMsgEvents: IMessageEvents); Overload;
    Destructor Destroy; Override;
  End;

Implementation

Constructor TChatClient.Create(iMsgEvents: IMessageEvents);
Begin
  Inherited Create;
  self.iMsgEvents := iMsgEvents;
End;

Destructor TChatClient.Destroy;
Begin
  Inherited Destroy;
End;
```

**Main:**

```
cChatManager: TChatManager;
self.cChatManager := TChatManager.Create;
self.cChatManager.Free; // Failed
```

Anyone can explain what I'm implementing bad? Thanks.

**NOTE:** The classes are not complete, i deleted some methods where release objects, etc...

Regards.

Comment: @LU RD thanks for response. The classes are not complete, I deleted the methods where I release the objects. But the problem is not there.

Comment: @David, yeah, I know, in fact in the first line I already said that I had previously posted a similar problem. The fact is that, although the problem was solved, but I did not understand exactly what is causing the error to find out and so I had to open a new topic.

Comment: I thought I explained that already. Perhaps not well enough. The point is that the interface references control the lifetime. You so ply have to stop holding references other than interface references.

Comment: @David yeah, i know but I had left some doubt. I have to learn more. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is the following method of `TInterfacedObject`:

```
procedure TInterfacedObject.BeforeDestruction;
begin
  if RefCount <> 0 then
    Error(reInvalidPtr);
end;
```

Your code is destroying the `TChatManager` instance having nonzero `RefCount` field because it is referenced by the `TChatClient` instance.

---

The OP code cannot be fixed and should be redesigned because in the current form the `TChatManager` instances should be destroyed in `TChatClient` destructor (by setting `iMsgEvents:= nil`) and this is weird! :)

Comment: That's what raises the exception. The real problem is the subversion of reference counted lifetime management caused by assigning to `cChatManager`, a variable of type `TChatManager`.

Comment: @user246408 thanks, now I understand why this error appeared. David thank you too for response.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - this is good question; sure mixing object and interface references is bad design but to find the bug itself is interesting thing.